# Build once, deploy many, with Angular-CLI

Tags: deployment, angular-cli

I'm using `angular-cli` (beta 26). For local development it's great, but I'm struggling to see how it can fit into a more serious "build once, deploy many" type of pipeline?

I'm using the built-in concept of an `environment` to store environment specific information, e.g. connection strings. But I'm required to specify the environment at build time, by using `ng build --environment=xyz`. This basically means I have to do a fresh build for every deployment. Idealy I'd like to select my environment at runtime (much like can be done with ASP.NET Core for example).

Am I missing something here? Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: We had a similar problem, wanting to have different environments with different IDs for an analytics service; we ended up using SSI to include the tracking code at serve time, and dropping in the appropriate ID in an HTML file at deploy time, which isn't ideal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was quite thoroughly discussed in the https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855#issuecomment-274803729. Probably you know the answer already, but since it's not linked here I'm posting so anyone can see it.

Basically angular-cli environments are designed to be build-connected, so we have to custom-load e.g. a json file with runtime config.

Answer (score 0):

I missed [this awesome guide by juristr](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/) the first time I've checked the accepted answer's link and just want to have it here separately.
I picked up from multiple sources (and lots of trying) the same things which are really nicely broken down in detail in that guide. So if you would ever be in those shoes, I would gladly recommend to go through it!